# Array of list<string>, inserting a string behaves weird

Tags: c++, string, list, debugging

I wanted to make different kinds of hash tables using an array of lists with type `string`. Thus, I created:

```
list<string> hashtableFold[arraysize];
list<string> hashtableSelect[arraysize];
```

In a hashing function, `position` is calculated and then passed to a quite simple insert function:

```
Hash::insert(Hash::hashtableFold, position, contents);
```

of which the code is:

```
void Hash::insert(list<string> whichList[arraysize], int pos, string contents) {
    whichList[pos].push_back(str);
```

}

However, if I print `hashtableFold` (using the following code), the table is empty :(.

```
void Hash::print(list<string> whichList[arraysize]) {
    //loop over array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
        cout << i << ": ";
        list<string>::iterator k;
        //loop over list
        if (whichList[i].empty()) {
            cout << "empty";
        } // if
        else for (k = whichList[i].begin(); k != whichList[i].end(); k++)
            cout << *k << " | ";
        cout << endl;
    } // for
}
```

What's going wrong here?

For the interested, here is the complete source code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9844620/ds4.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two hash tables, here the relevant extracts from your code with comments

```
class DigitFold : public Hash // every DigitFold has its own hash table
{
};

int main()
{
    Hash hash; // first hash table
    DigitFold df; // contains second hash table

    setInput(stream);
    df.fold(stream);

    hash.print(hash.hashtableFold);
}
```

If you look at the code for `DigitFold::fold` you'll see that it adds items to it's own hash table (the second hash table), but you print out the hash table declared on the first line of main (the first hash table). That hash table hasn't had anything added to it.

Change the last line to

```
df.print(df.hashtableFold);
```

That might work (assuming no other bugs).

But really the code is a bit confused, you need to rethink the realtionship between `DigitFold` and `Hash` and redesign `Hash` too. The `insert` and `print` methods should not take the internals of a `Hash` object as parameters. Since they are methods of `Hash` they already have access to these, to make them parameters is just confusing.

Comment: Great! Thanks. However, now the lists get filled with empty strings.. :p https://www.dropbox.com/s/bltf9eqisnsz09y/Screenshot%202013-11-23%2015.54.24.png

Comment: Well as I said, assuming no other bugs.

Comment: ;) Will ook into that. Thanks!

Comment: Why are the methods taking copies of things? Or are they?

Comment: @doctorlove That had me confused for a while. Because the parameters are really pointers (even though they look like arrays) the answer is no.